# Maven: do not deploy wars into the repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a problem with Maven: it is deploying also the wars into the release/snapshot repository.

Does exist any way to upload only pom and jar types?

Comment: Why don't you want to deploy them cause they are artifacts created by the build process? Why would you like to have only pom's ? You can't do anything without the other artifacts..

Comment: I don't want to deploy a WAR into a Nexus repository. But only JARs and POMs. A war i intended to be deployed in an application server (Tomcat, JBoss...), but not in a Nexus

Comment: Why not? The war is needed to deploy the Tomcat/Jboss which you usually can do from nexus...